# How to change the visibility of a template button in a listbox?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-7, silverlight-3.0, binding

I am creating a Windows Phone application and I have a problem with a listbox template.
I would like to hide the "MoreButton" defined in the MoreListBoxStyle at runtime. 
I tried to create a property and bind it to the visibility property of the button but it doesn't work.

How should I do ?

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="MoreListBoxStyle" TargetType="ListBox">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Disabled"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBox">
                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewer" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                        <StackPanel >
                            <ItemsPresenter  />
                            <Button x:Name="MoreButton"   Content="{Binding Path=LocaleResources.More, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}" Height="67" Margin="0,0,8,0" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}" BorderThickness="0" FontSize="17" FontWeight="Bold" Click="MoreButton_Click"  />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

And my listbox is :

```
<ListBox x:Name="RandomListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Grid.Row="1" Style="{StaticResource MoreListBoxStyle}">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding MyText}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="440" Margin="0,10"   Name="{Binding MyId}" ManipulationCompleted="TextBlock_ManipulationCompleted" />
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Width="440" TextWrapping="Wrap" TextAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,0,15" />
                                <Rectangle Width="440" Height="3" Fill="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"></Rectangle>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

                </ListBox>
```

Comment: When do you want to hide the button? When a particular item is selected or depending on some condition? Also as to the property that you mentioned - is it a property of the DataSource or the current page?

Comment: I use a pivot control and when the user switch to another pivot item I would like the button to be hidden if the list doesn't have any value. I created a property on the current page and tried to bind it to the Visibility property of the button.

Comment: `Visibility = {Binding path = YourProperty}"` should work. Make sure you are setting all(DataContext + Property) up right

Comment: I defined the x:name of my page to be "HomePage" and I added this : Visibility="{ Binding MoreButtonVisibility, ElementName=HomePage}"  But the value of the MoreButtonVisibility is set only when I define it in the page constructor but not when I define it from an event method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand your question I think that you have two options:

If you are using a CLR property than make sure that you have implemented **INotifyPropertyChanged** like for example:

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
       ...
    Visibility sampleProperty;
    public Visibility SampleProperty
    {
        get
        {
            return sampleProperty;
        }
        set
        {
            sampleProperty = value;
            // Call OnPropertyChanged whenever the property is updated
            OnPropertyChanged("SampleProperty");
        }

    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
  }
}
```